# What does "output_dir="${1%/}" mean in .sh file?

Tags: bash

I have not seen the usage like this.Anyone can provide relevant information? The source code [im2txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/im2txt/im2txt/data/download_and_preprocess_mscoco.sh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [bash manual:](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)

> ${parameter%word}
>   ${parameter%%word}
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see Pattern Matching). If the pattern matches **a trailing portion** of the expanded value of *parameter,* then the result of the expansion is the value of *parameter* with the **shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case)** or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted. [...]

I emphasized the relevant alternative. The *parameter* in question is $1, i.e. the first command line argument the script was called with. The pattern is a simple `/` which will be removed if present. In other words, the expansion removes an optional trailing slash.

Demonstration (the `y` case shows that it's just a trailing pattern, `z` demonstrates no match):

```
$ x=aaa/; y=aaa/bbb; z=aaa; echo "$x    ->      ${x%/}"; echo "$y       ->      ${y%/}"; echo "$z       ->      ${z%/}"
aaa/    ->      aaa
aaa/bbb ->      aaa/bbb
aaa     ->      aaa
```

Answer (score 1):

It basically removes the last "/" character from the ending of the first string received as a parameter of the script in cause.
If you had "/home/users/" as a string, then `output_dir` would become "/home/users"
You can find more details on string manipulation in bash [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).